# Deleting data from table view and from sql

Tags: java, database, javafx, database-connection

**I want to delete the data from table view and from SQL,after i tried almost everything i don't know where the problem is?**

```
public void DeleteButton(ActionEvent event) throws SQLException, 
    ClassNotFoundException{

   String sql = "Delete from Add_NewOrder where No=?";
   try{
       pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);
       pst.setString(1, comboBoxTable.getValue());
       int i = pst.executeUpdate();
       if(i==1){
            Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.ERROR);
            alert.setTitle("Information Dialog");
            alert.setHeaderText(null);
            alert.setContentText("Te dhenat nuk jane shlyer!");
            alert.showAndWait();
            loadDataFromDataBase();
            clearTextField();
       }
   }catch(SQLException ex){
        Logger.getLogger(AddNewOrderController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE,null,ex);
   }
}
```

Comment: @Anchit Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Comment: unrelated to your problem: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them. Looks like you are not inclined to learn ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which part isn't working?

I see lots of problems with your code:

1. Connection and PreparedStatement appear to be class variables.  I'd keep PreparedStatement in method scope and close it in a finally block.
2. Method is doing two things: database and Swing UI change.  Separate them into individual classes and methods.  Test them separately and combine them when both are working.
3. Mixing UI and processing code in the same class is something I try to avoid.  I'd partition them into separate classes.

Comment: i did what u said but,i think the problem is not there but,somewhere else,it could be for example (pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);
           pst.setString(1, comboBoxTable.getValue());
           int i = pst.executeUpdate();)

Comment: i think the problem is here somewhere

Comment: I'd recommend learning and following Java coding standards.  Your method and variable names should start with lower case letters.  I'd encapsulate the database behavior into a separate class, inject that into a Listener class, and attach that to the JButton.